# How can I create a java program that multiplies my Text?

Tags: java

I have to write a program where I can simply write something 
in a textfield and a number in my numberfield. 
Something like this:

1.textField: Hello

2.numberField: 8

3.Output: Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello

I tried this:

```
 int i= count.getInt();

 int e;

String t= text.getText();

    for (e=i;e<i ;e++ ) {
      ausgabe.append(""+e);
    } // end of for


    ausgabe.append(""+t);



    ausgabe.append("\n");
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: multiplies text? seriously? take a look at  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I am from germany and i didnt know how to say it. Can you help me ?

Comment: `e` is an int, why are you adding this to your string?  You should be appending `t` to your string within your loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are appending the text outside the loop, this must work:

```
int i= count.getInt();

String t = text.getText();
for (int e = 0; e < i; e++) {
  ausgabe.append(" " + t);
}// end of for

ausgabe.append("\n");
```

Answer (score 2):

What do you expect this loop to do?

```
for (e=i;e<i ;e++ ) {
```

If `e` starts at the value of `i`, then `e<i` will *always* be false.  A value can't simultaneously be both *equal to* and *less than* another value.

Maybe you meant to start at `0` instead?:

```
for (e=0; e<i; e++) {
```

---

Additionally, this is going to append `e` to your string:

```
ausgabe.append(""+e);
```

`e` is the *counter* for the loop.  It's a *number*.  Don't you want to append the *text* to the string?:

```
ausgabe.append(""+t);
```

Comment: @MikeChristensen: I have... no idea why I did that.  Thanks!

Comment: Thank you really much. But the text appends always on more time. When i want 5 Hello´s it´s giving me 6 Hello´s.

Comment: @brickzdesign: The line of code immediately after your loop is appending the text one more time.  If you don't want to append the text one more time, you probably don't need that line of code.

Comment: @David: Thank you sooo much i have spent 2 days searching for it on the internet. I thank you really much.

Answer (score 0):

```
String t = "Hello";
int counter = 8;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
     sb.append(t);
     sb.append("-");
} // end of for
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

replace the last "-" and there you have it....

Comment: What do you mean with replacing the "-"                                                               What do i have to put in there ?